# how to merge point lines algorithme

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, merge

I am writing a tool where I can detect A4 paper. So far what I do is blur an image then get the outlines of the image. Then I use a Hough line detection to get all the lines in the image. The lines on the image below come out of my detection.

What I want to do next is merge all lines with almost the same angle near each other. But I can't get this to work. So in the image below you can see there are like 5 lines on top of the paper, and I need to merge them into 1. Same gos for all other lines.

[image: houghdetection]

When I get my lines and I extend them to the edge of the image and add intersection detection (the round red icons), I get a bit lost. Thats why I need to merge the lines to be able to detect where the paper corners are.

[image]

What I have at the moment is to remove a line when it intersects and the angle difference <= 2

```
Dim remove As New List(Of Integer)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        For j As Integer = i + 1 To lines.Count - 1
            If Not remove.Contains(i) AndAlso Not remove.Contains(j) Then
                Dim pt As PointF = computeIntersect(lines(i).P1, lines(i).P2, lines(j).P1, lines(j).P2)
                If pt.X >= 0 AndAlso pt.Y >= 0 Then
                    Dim angle1 As Integer = GetAngleBetweenPoints(lines(i).P1, lines(i).P2)
                    Dim angle2 As Integer = GetAngleBetweenPoints(lines(j).P1, lines(j).P2)
                    If Math.Abs(angle1 - angle2) <= 2 Then
                        remove.Add(i)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Dim tmp As New List(Of LineSegment2D)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        If Not remove.Contains(i) Then
            tmp.Add(lines(i))
        End If
    Next
```

So my question is: How to merge the lines of the first screenshot which are close to each other and almost have the same angle or have the same angle?

Comment: What an incredibly random photo...

Answer (score 1):

For each line segment, identify a line at right angles to that line segment, at the midpoint of the segment.  Call that the normal line.  Your candidates for merging are any two lines that intersect that normal line within a "close enough" distance at an angle "close enough" to 90 degrees.

So, for example, suppose that the line segment goes from `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)`.    The midpoint is `((x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2)`.  The normal line will pass through that midpoint and `((x1 + x2)/2 + y2 - y1, (y1 + y2)/2 + x1 - x2)`.  (Note the reversing indexes of `y2-y1` and `x1-x2`.  That makes it be at right angles.)

You could then set a rule that any other line segment whose extended line intersects that normal within 10 pixels of the midpoint, at an angle between 88 and 92 degrees, should be merged with the first into a longer line segment.

Comment: I don't really undestand your answer, could you give an example?

Comment: @Niels Did my revised explanation help?